# How to create a yml while to create create a new IAM::ROLE in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, yaml, aws-cloudformation

In AWS cloud formation template how to create a new lambda(test_lambda_role) role

which is having access to s3:getObject,  RDS access(rds-db:connect),

```
Resources:
    Role:  
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            RoleName: !Sub test_lambda_role
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal: 
                          Lambda:
                              - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:saml-provider/${pSamlProviderAdmin}"
                      Action: 
                        - rds-db:connect
```

Lambda function not creating with above template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssumeRolePolicyDocument` is for a **trust policy**, as explained in:

- [Creating a role to delegate permissions to an AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html)

Thus a template with only a lambda execution role could be:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters: 

  testlambdarole:
    Type: String
    Default: role-name
      
Resources: 

  Role:  
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref testlambdarole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'               
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: {'Service': ['lambda.amazonaws.com']}
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']      
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3Access
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - s3:getObject
                Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: RdsAccess
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - rds-db:connect
                Resource: "*"
```

You would need to adjust `Policies` to exactly what you require.

Comment: just adding one more thing if i need redshift access also  is this below thing correct ` - PolicyName: RdsAccess
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - redshift-db:connect
                Resource: "*"`

Comment: @Maws Yes, you can add new policies for other permissions. There are other possibilities, but I think this way is most generic.